# Bulk insert with ignore duplicate records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I am trying to do bulk insert based on the condition if email exist it should ignore the record.
Currently my approach is bit long. Firstly I am filtering the email which aren't in the users table and then I am doing insert which is firing multiple insert queries. I checked in rails 6 we have insert_all and upsert_all but not sure how we can achieve the same thing with these methods.

```
user_email = ["aniket@rpxcorp.com", "assasdas@gmail.com"]

##Only find those users which doesn't exists in users table

user_email = user_email - User.all.pluck(:email)

records = []
role = Role.find_by(name: "admin")
user_email.each do |record|
    records.push({email: record, password: "12345678", password_confirmation: "12345678", role: role})
end

#it will run multiple insert commands which I want to avoid

u = User.create(records)
```

Comment: Usually you use `find_or_create_by` which can test before creating.

Comment: @tadman Does it work with multiple records? Also, is it going to fire multiple insert query or single insert query?

Comment: It'll do a test for each insert, but that should be quick unless you're inserting thousands. There's also options like [`insert_all`](https://blog.bigbinary.com/2019/04/15/bulk-insert-support-in-rails-6.htmlZ) which if you have uniqueness constraints on the database can skip duplicates for you.

Comment: It won't skip duplicates it raises an exception

Comment: Which won't? These come in two versions, like `insert_all` vs. `insert_all!`.

Comment: Do you have uniqueness constraints at the database level?

Comment: Yes I do have a constraint on email

Comment: @tadman In postgres when we do upsert ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT email 
DO NOTHING;  We have a feature call do nothing. So, any similar feature do we have in rails?

Comment: Why not use `insert_all` then? Do you get an exception? If so what? You need to explain. In Rails `insert_all` should do the `DO NOTHING` part for you.

Comment: When I try to use insert_all I am getting this error ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'password' for User.  I will let you know if the insert_all with do nothign works

Comment: If this is using a layer like Devise and `password` is something handled by the model then you can't use `insert_all` as a bypass, you have to use `create` and let the `before_validation` hooks kick in. The `insert_all` is a low-level insert.

Comment: Yeah in my case I am using devise. And I was looking for the solutions. But thx for the informations.

Comment: Devise does a *lot* of model-level work you can't skip. If you have other models that are just "dumb data" then this works fine.

Comment: Got it I will keep that in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments by @tadman for any model which is backed by devise we cannot do bulk Insert